# problemas SessionFactory da null

Tags: java, registro

No consigo realizar la inserción en la tabla Clientes, al llegar a la linea 65 de la clase operaciones me da error y me salta la excepcion.
Alguien tiene en mente alguna solucion o me puede ayudar??????

No se como algo tan sencillo como un registro se puede complicar tanto en java...
He realizado varios cambios y no consigo que funcione.

**CLASE QUE CONTROLA EL REGISTRO**

```
package servlets;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import mvc.Clientes;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import mvc.Clientes;
import mvc.Operaciones;


@WebServlet("/ControlaRegistros")
public class ControlaRegistro extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private SessionFactory sf;    //añadido
     @Override
     //añadido
     public void init(ServletConfig configura) throws ServletException {

         this.sf =  (SessionFactory)configura.getServletContext().getAttribute("SF");
    }

    public ControlaRegistro() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        try {
            //  String dato = req.getParameter("ape"); ESTO NO NOS FUNCIONA
                //Proceso de la libreria commons.fileupload para obtener el archivo enviado al servidor
                String ruta = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("\\")  + "\\imagenes\\";
                System.out.println(ruta);
                Operaciones ope = new Operaciones(this.sf);
                HttpSession sesion =  request.getSession(true);
                ServletContext aplicacion = request.getServletContext();  
                ArrayList<String> lista = null;
                lista = (ArrayList<String>)aplicacion.getAttribute("lista"); 
                if (lista==null)                                           
                    lista = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Clientes cliente = new Clientes(items.get(0).getString(),items.get(1).getString(),
                                                items.get(2).getString(), items.get(3).getString() );

                ope.nuevoUsuario(cliente);
                ruta +=  items.get(5).getName();
                items.get(5).write(new File(ruta));
                sesion.setAttribute("usuario", cliente);
                if (!lista.contains(cliente.getUsuario()) )            
                          lista.add(cliente.getUsuario());              
                aplicacion.setAttribute("lista", lista);                
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("entrada.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }


    }
```

**FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="mvc.Clientes,java.util.*"%>







<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Formulario de entrada</title>
</head>
<body>


<p>

<h2>FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO</h2>
<center>
<form action="hacerregistro" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    USUARIO: <input type="text" name="usuario" /><br/>
    NOMBRE: <input type="text" name="clave" /><br/>
    APELLIDOS: <input type="text" name="apellidos" /><br/>
    FOTO: <input type="file" name="foto" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="ENTRAR" /><br/>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**CLASE OPERACIONES**

```
package mvc;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;


public class Operaciones {

    private Session ses;
    private Transaction tx;


     public Operaciones(SessionFactory sf) {
            ses  = sf.openSession();       

     }


     public void bajausuario(Clientes cliente, String ruta)
        {
            try {
                 tx = ses.beginTransaction();
                 Clientes cli = ses.get(Clientes.class, cliente.getUsuario());
                if (cli!=null)
                {
                     ses.delete(cli);
                     tx.commit();
                };

            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
            finally {
                new File(ruta, cliente.getFoto()).delete();
                ses.close();
            }
        }


     public void nuevoUsuario(Clientes cliente)
        {
            try {
                 tx = ses.beginTransaction();
                ses.save(cliente);
                try {
                    tx.commit();
                } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                    System.out.println("USUARIO DUPLICADO");
                    System.out.printf("MENSAJE: %s%n", e.getMessage());
                    System.out.printf("COD ERROR: %d%n", e.getErrorCode());
                    System.out.printf("ERROR SQL: %s%n", e.getSQLException().getMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR NO CONTROLADO....");
                tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                ses.close();
            }
        }

     public Clientes validarUsuario(String usuario, String clave)
        {
            Clientes cli = (Clientes) ses.get(Clientes.class, usuario);
            if (cli!=null && cli.getApellidos().equals(clave))
                return cli;
            else return null;

        }


     public Clientes validarUsuario(String usuario)
        {
            Clientes cli = (Clientes) ses.get(Clientes.class, usuario);
            return cli;  //si no lo encuentra get devuele null
        }

}
```

**TABLA UTILIZADA **

```
    package mvc;
// Generated 19-feb-2020 0:30:53 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.1.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Clientes generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes", catalog = "pruebapablo")
public class Clientes implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String usuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String foto;

    public Clientes() {
    }

    public Clientes(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Clientes(String usuario, String nombre, String apellidos, String foto) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "usuario", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getUsuario() {
        return this.usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    @Column(name = "nombre", length = 20)
    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Column(name = "apellidos", length = 40)
    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    @Column(name = "foto", length = 50)
    public String getFoto() {
        return this.foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

}
```

No consigo realizar la inserción en la tabla Clientes, al llegar a la linea 65 de la clase operaciones me da error y me salta la excepcion.
Alguien tiene en mente alguna solucion o me puede ayudar??????

No se como algo tan sencillo como un registro se puede complicar tanto en java...
He realizado varios cambios y no consigo que funcione.

Comment: Te ha faltado poner cuál es la línea 65 y de paso la excepción que te salta.

Comment: en la clase que controla el registro al llegar a :     Operaciones ope = new Operaciones(this.sf);    Y me lanza el   e.printStackTrace();

Comment: ¿Y la excepción es? El mensaje de la excepción es el que te da la pista del problema. ¿Será que el parámetro que le pasas al constructor `this.sf` es `null` y lo que te da es un `NullPointerException` dentro del constructor al hacer `sf.openSession()`?

Comment: si, me da NullPointerException. Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: No lo se, pero no estaría mal que modificaras tu pregunta e indicaras que el problema lo tienes en la obtención del `SessionFactory` que te está retornando null. Obtendrás mejor ayuda que con la descripción actual.

Comment: gracias!!!!!!!!